# From Windows 8 could not send mail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

We wrote the code to send the mail through the Gmail SMTP server. It worked fine in Windows 7 machine but it didn't work in Windows 8 machine.

**Configurations**

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server
requires TLS or SSL: smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465
```

**Code**

```
final String username = "aaa@gmail.com";
        final String password = "aaa";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            String itemNames = getItemNames(itemSet);
            String purchaseNote = "";

            if (delAddress == null) {
                purchaseNote = "You can collect the items in our store by giveing the tracking number with in 10 days.";
            } else {
                purchaseNote = "N/A";
            }

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("arjun@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("SuperDeal Purchase Detail");
            message.setText("Dear " + customer.getFullName() + "\n\n" + "Purchase Items: " + itemNames + "\n" + "Total Cost: " + totalCost + "\n" + "Tracking No: " + trackingNumber + "\n" + "Purchase Note: " + purchaseNote + "\n\n" + "Note: If you have any queries please call to our hot line 0112345647 any time.");

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
```

**Error**

```
68352 [http-bio-8080-exec-55] ERROR com.superdeal.mail.MailSender - can't determine local email address
javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:906)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.superdeal.mail.MailSender.send(MailSender.java:66)
    at com.superdeal.servlet.AddOrderServlet.processRequest(AddOrderServlet.java:91)
    at com.superdeal.servlet.AddOrderServlet.doPost(AddOrderServlet.java:239)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
71600 [http-bio-8080-exec-54] ERROR com.superdeal.mail.MailSender - can't determine local email address
javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:906)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at com.superdeal.mail.MailSender.send(MailSender.java:66)
    at com.superdeal.servlet.AddOrderServlet.processRequest(AddOrderServlet.java:91)
    at com.superdeal.servlet.AddOrderServlet.doPost(AddOrderServlet.java:239)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please advice me why this works fine in Windows7 and does not work in Windows8.

Comment: Java is designed to be OS-agnostic, so there must be some inherent difference as to how you're building and running your code. Are library version and build process the same?

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software on Windows 8?

Comment: The error implies that the lack of a sender address is the problem.

Comment: Can you please post the output of  InetAddress me = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); System.out.println(me.getHostName()); when executing on the faulting Win8 machine? Please post also Java Version and JavaMail Version. As @tripleee mentioned it a problem with the "from" address of the message. But the real question why it works on Win7 and not on Win8? Can you make sure that the java properties user.name is equal in both execution environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set a From address in your message, and JavaMail was unable to determine an address to use.  The latter usually occurs because the JDK is unable to determine the host name of your local host, perhaps because it used DHCP to get an IP address, and perhaps because the name service is configured incorrectly on the local machine.

In any event, the simple fix is to set a From address on your message, which you should be doing anyway.